# CSS, hover one element, affect another

Tags: css, hover, element

When i hover a "li a" can i then affect another element in plain CSS?

becuase I'm trying to make a box slide in, as a background element, when hovering my link.
Exactly like this sites navigation, just instead of when activated, it works with hover

http://www.zindhai.com

this is my code

```
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #C3E1FF;
    font-weight: 700;
}

nav ul li span:hover{
    -webkit-transform:translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
}

nav ul li span{
    height:43px;
    width:300px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#47525D;
    -webkit-transform:translate(300px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    background-position:initial initial;
    background-repeat:initial initial;
}
```

thanks in advance!

This is how it looks now;

http://jsfiddle.net/mbyc3tf9/

Comment: provide HTML too, and make a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please see the instructions on [making a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: jsfiddle.net added :) please take a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/mbyc3tf9/1/ i have added a sub-menu when you `hover` on `li` it will show sub `li`

Comment: Okay, but that's not my problem, it's the box on the right, that i need to slide in, when hovering on the li

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need move the span, when you put your mouse over the a, add this

```
nav ul li a:hover > span {}
```

Comment: Thank you! it works, but now my a hover effect has dissapeared?

Comment: you need add nav ul li a:hover {} and nav ul li a:hover > span {}

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly :)
Actually i need help to another question if you have the time, do you know how i hide the span, so it only appears when hovering the li. Because right now it's visible to the right of the li

Comment: Yes, add display: none; to nav ul li span and add display:block; to nav ul li a:hover > span

Comment: Yep it worked, though the "animation" disappeared, so the span isn't sliding in from the side, it just appears :/

Comment: you need add the animation code in the nav ul li a:hover > span

Comment: nav ul li a:hover > span{
 -webkit-transform:translate(0px, 0px);
   -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
   transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
 display:block;
}

This is my code, and that's not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's pretty easy to do. Assuming your HTML is called something like `.myElement` for example. All you need to do is...

`nav ul li a:hover .myElement { ... }`

Then enter your CSS inside the `{ }`.

Comment: could you maybe give me an example with my code above?
I've tried several things at it doesn't work.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with my css.